# How can i upload image from project 1 to project 2 with laravel?

Tags: laravel, image, upload, store

I created 2 Laravel projects 1 for back-end and the second for the front-end.

So what i need to do is to upload images from back-end to front-end using Laravel store method.
My code:

```
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'domainPath');
        $attributes['image'] = $path;
    }
```

in the filesystems.php i added:

```
    'domainPath' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_DOMAIN').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

in the env file i add APP_DOMAIN = front-end absolute path which is: 
       `D:/wamp64/www/projects/beytiresidence`

Comment: what error you are getting.?

Comment: the image is uploaded to back-end (storage/app/public/images) not to front-end where i want it. i try to clear: cache via php artisan but no success.

Comment: Storage::disk('domainPath')->url('$backendImgePath');  it will work on front end

Comment: APP_DOMAIN= should bt http url not `D:/wamp64/www/projects/beytiresidence`

Comment: i changed the  APP_DOMAIN to http://beytiresidence/storage/app/public and the code is :

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'domainPath');
            $attributes['image'] = $path;
        }

        'domainPath' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_DOMAIN').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
APP_DOMAIN=http://beytiresidence/storage/app/public

Still upload the image to back-end ( storage/app/public/images)

Comment: APP_DOMAIN is wrong please correct it

Comment: you mean it needs (http://)  it is removed by stackoverflow.com

Comment: ohh  `\Storage::disk('domainPath')->put('image',$request->image );` use this to upload file or change default disk

Comment: problem was with the code i add it in the filesystem the correct code is like below



 if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
           $path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'domainPath');
            $attributes['image'] = $path;
        }

  'domainPath' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => ('D:\wamp64\www\projects\beytiresidence\storage\app\public'),
            'url' => env('APP_DOMAIN').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],


in env file APP_DOMAIN=http://beytiresidence

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Create one project for both front end and black end. Because every project has it's encryption key while send/submitting form data as a token. Two projects have different keys. Although you can still achieve this task using Passport.

Comment: @KashifSaleem the problem you talk about it can be solved by that we can upload the images to the back-end and then  the front-end can read from there.
but is there any other approach you can suggest it to make a clean project and separate the front-end and the back-end  because each one has it is own web.php file and routes and login and ....and i don't want to put them all in same files.